# How did Walt know where Lydia was going to sit?

Tags: breaking-bad

Near the end of *Breaking Bad* the sinister ex-chemistry teacher was lurking in wait of Lydia as she walked in for a cup of coffee, and had placed the Stevia sweetener at an empty table that she just so happened to have chosen to sit at.

But how did Walt know she was going to sit there?

Comment: Didn't she always sit at the same table?

Comment: She was a creature of habit - that is the only thing that enabled Walt to get to her. Same table every time, same order, same stevia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lydia was a creature of habit. She always sat at the same table, always made the same order, and always added stevia to her drink. That is the only thing that enabled Walt to get to her - in fact, she made it easy for him.